# While printing the page the header moves up after 3,4 pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I don't know how to explain this issue. In my html web page the data is showing perfectly inside each page. When I try to print in the initial pages the data table fits inside the page but after 2,3 pages the header moves up. For more clarity I am posting the images below.
I am looping the same table with different data.
First Page
[image: First Page]

Third Page
[image: Third Page]

At the end of the page it shows like this
[image: At the end of the page it shows like this]

My css code:

```
<style>

.verticaltext{
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform:scale(-1);
}


page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
/*  margin-bottom: 0.5cm; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

page[size="A4"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}

page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 21cm;
}

.table-wtotbr {
     
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wtbr {
    width: 100%;
}

.table-wtotbr th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table-wtbr th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container-table {
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99% !important;
    font-size: 11px;
/*  border: 2px solid red; */
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 95%;
}

.checkbox {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>


<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print {
    html, body {
/*          border: 5px solid red;  */
        color: black;
        margin: 2px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100vh !important;
        /*      overflow: hidden !important;   */
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    @page {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        size: A4 landscape;
        margin: 0 !important;
        height: 99% !important; 
    }
    .footer {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .container-table {
    border: 5px solid red;
        overflow: hidden !important;    
        color: black;
        width: 99% !important;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding following codes in the container div.

```
    .container-table {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-before: avoid;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        height: 99% !important;
        padding-top:10px;
        /*  border: 5px solid red; */
        /*      overflow: hidden !important;     */
        color: black;
        width: 99% !important;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
```